# How to calculate a vector to move towards based on a central origin point

Tags: math, vector, position

Hey so I am having some issue with vector math that I need to resolve to make my code work. What I am trying to do is this:

Lets say we have three objects:

- Object A is the central object
- Object B is a few meters away from A on a 45 degree from A's position
- Object C is also a few meters away from A but on a 90 degree angle from A's position

A bit like this:

```
 B
AC
```

Now what I need to do is get a vector coordinate point 10m more away from A that both B and C will move to when A is activated. So, when I activate A, B will continue along the 45 deg angle to currentPos + newPos and C will move along the 90 degree angle to currentPos + newPos. All of this has to be based on the position of A. The objects have to be moving away from A's central position.

Vector math is something I am not too familiar with and I am sort of struggling a little here to figure out how to get the new position for B and C based on their current angle to A and A position, so thought I would ask you more knowledgable people for help.

Would you please write any responses in a straightforward manner, so I can easily convert the idea into code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am following your picture, which I would call a zero degree angle from A's position for C. Let us suppose we call your location of A (0,0).

It looks like in your case you could add (10,0) to C's current spot. For B, you could (5sqrt(2),5sqrt(2)). More generally, to move n units at an angle theta (measure in radians in most languages), add n(cos (theta), sine (theta)).

I am taking this approach because you said the angle was known and A was the center of our universe and everything is relative to it. If that were not the case, an approach that looked at B-A and C-A as vectors and took their sizes, then added the right amounts of them, might be called for instead.